# sbt proguard plugin don't place my classes to jar

Tags: scala, sbt, proguard

That is funny but my project configuration does everything to generate executable jar except adding my project classes to final jar:

```
import sbt._

class ProjectDescriptor(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) with ProguardProject{

  override def mainClass = Some("org.myproject.MyClass")

  override def proguardOptions = List(
    "-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }",
    "-dontoptimize",
    "-dontobfuscate",
    proguardKeepLimitedSerializability,
    proguardKeepAllScala,
    "-keep interface scala.ScalaObject"
  )
  val scalaLibraryPath = "<...>/project/boot/scala-2.8.0/lib"
  override def proguardInJars = super.proguardInJars +++ Path.fromFile(scalaLibraryPath)
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ProGuard, I use the OneJar plugin to create executable jars with [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar). It's a lot simpler since you don't have to mess with a bunch of options like ProGuard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `ProguardProject` provides. But I think you can try

```
ProguardKeys.options in Proguard ++= Seq(
  ProguardOptions.keepMain("com.you.main.class")
)
```

This works for me.